# MySQL alter view security

Tags: mysql, sql, security, view

I created a view with user root@'%' leaving the SQL SECURITY as the default DEFINER. Now that I deleted that user for security reasons, nobody else can access the view...

```
ALTER SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW view_x;
```

gives error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual... near '' at line 1"

Here's the documentation on MySQLs website

ALTER
    [ALGORITHM = {UNDEFINED | MERGE | TEMPTABLE}]
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    [SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }]
    VIEW view_name [(column_list)]
    AS select_statement
    [WITH [CASCADED | LOCAL] CHECK OPTION]

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have left out the mandatory "AS select_statement" part. You must specify the sql for the view.

> ALTER SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW view_x AS ... insert your sql here ...;

Comment: I was trying to avoid re-writing the view, but ended up pulling the definition from information_schema.views. With the sql it works, thanks